# How to set a variable Angular inside of a template (Blade)

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-blade

i have this:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in reddit.items'>
```

i wanna set an item attribute (@{{item.content}}) to blade if

```
@if(Auth::check() and ifFav(Auth::user()->id, @{{item.id}}) == false)
    <li>
        html...
    </li>
@endif
```

but laravel set an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '{'
```

Comment: did you try <% item.id %> ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the item object to your view properly?
If so it should be

```
$item->id
```

instead of

```
@{{item.id}}
```

as it's in an if statement.

Remember, as according to [the current doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views), you should pass your item object like follow :

```
return view('your.view.template')->with('item', $itemInstance);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to pass or assign a valid json data to angular variable.
Second of all data need to be escaped.

If you're passing object to blade just escape the passed object.
Or ir you're passing a string, first encode it like json_encode($passedData) and escape it.

You can escape data in blade like :- ***{!! $passedData !!}***

Example 1:

var $scope.a = {!! $passedData ||} //if its an object.

Example 2:

var $scope.a = {!! json_encode($passedData) !!} //if its a string